# what javascript codes can be used to highlight administrative territories on google maps, possibly with coordinates, similar to the image below?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

[Image of Microsoft MapPoint Territories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSarp.png)
I want to highlight different territories with their actual boundaries in the Greater Toronto Area in Canada. I have done so using mapPoint and want to do same in Google Maps. what JavaScript codes can these be done with? Is there a code where you can add coordinates of a region and then select them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple example for google-developer. it's only a triangle but the rules are the same (only more coordinates)

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
>   <head>
>     <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
>     <meta charset="utf-8">
>     <title>Simple Polygon</title>
>     <style>
>       html, body {
>         height: 100%;
>         margin: 0;
>         padding: 0;
>       }
>       #map {
>         height: 100%;
>       }
>     </style>
>   </head>
>   <body>
>     <div id="map"></div>
>     <script>
>
> // This example creates a simple polygon representing the Bermuda Triangle.
>
> function initMap() {
>   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
>     zoom: 5,
>     center: {lat: 24.886, lng: -70.268},
>     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
>   });
>
>   // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.
>   var triangleCoords = [
>     {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190},
>     {lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118},
>     {lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757},
>     {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190}
>   ];
>
>   // Construct the polygon.
>   var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
>     paths: triangleCoords,
>     strokeColor: '#FF0000',
>     strokeOpacity: 0.8,
>     strokeWeight: 2,
>     fillColor: '#FF0000',
>     fillOpacity: 0.35
>   });
>   bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
> }
>
>     </script>
>     <script async defer
>         src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```

as you can see here is create the polygon

the paths attribute contain the coordinates of the polygon, color stroke and fill,  color and opacity are for the aspect of the polygon

```
  // Construct the polygon.
  var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: triangleCoords,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35
  });
```

Comment: Thanks scaisEdge. Very helpful. And how about selecting multiple areas or polygons at once ? How can that be done?

Comment: If the answer is right please mark as accepted and or rate as useful, for selecting an area or multiple.,. You need add a listener to the polygon object and in the related callbak function you can do what you need..see this sample for a click event https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-arrays